# Proving $\sqrt 1+\sqrt 2+..+\sqrt n \approx\frac{2}{3} n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ asymptotically

Tags: asymptotics, riemann-sum

Let $n$ be a positive intiger, prove this asymptotic formula for large $n$

$$\sqrt1+\sqrt2+\cdots +\sqrt n=\frac{2}{3}n^{\frac{3}{2}}+\text{lower order}$$
using a Riemann sum.

Comment: The question does not say that the two sides are equal. Equality is   false even for $n=1$.

Comment: So you want to show that $\sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt{k} \simeq \int_0^n \sqrt{x} \operatorname d x$ ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I know but I think question wants an integration answer.

Comment: @SewerKeeper Yes but sqrt(x) integration limits are [0,1].

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I have edited the question to specify that the OP is asking for an asympotic formula with the term of largest order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can obtain your approximation as follows:
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^\frac12=n^\frac32\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^\frac12\frac1n=n^{\frac32}g\left(n\right)$$
where $g\left(n\right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^\frac12\frac1n$. Now for large $n$, we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g\left(n\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^\frac12\frac1n=\int_0^1x^\frac12\mathrm dx=\frac23$$
So for large $n$, we have $g\left(n\right)=\frac23+\left(\text{things vanish at large }n\right)$. Thus for large $n$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^\frac12=\left(\frac23+\text{things that vanish at large }n\right)n^\frac32\\
=\frac23n^\frac32+\text{lower order}$$